# Label focus does not change css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple form and wanted to highlight the focused labels by changing their background colors, but the jquery doesnt seem to work here. 
The console does not show any errors. Could someone please help me on this?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="qrForm">

    <label for="enter1">Enter<input id='enter1' type="radio" name="enter"></label>
    <label for="enter2">Exit<input id='enter2' type="radio" name="enter"></label><br>
    <label for="device1">Took a device<input id="device1" type="radio" name="device"></label>
    <label for="device2">Returned a device<input id="device2" type="radio" name="device"></label>
</form>

<script>
    $("label").focus(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#00CC66');
    });
</script>
```

I could actually finish it by adding/removing a class but I wonder why this one isn't working.

Comment: label:focus{background-color:#111;} . pure css

Comment: The <label> isnt focused. The <input> is focused

Answer (score 5):

why use js when you can do it in CSS?

```
label:focus {
    background-color: #00cc66;
}
```

you also want to add `tabindex=0` if you want your `label` elements to be focusable though, as if you e.g. click on a label, the *focus* is moved to the related `input` element

Alternatively, you can use the css next sibling selector as below:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" class="foo"><label for="foo">label</label>
```

and the css:

```
.foo:focus + label {
    background-color: #00cc66;
}
```

or play with different markup and css selectors

Comment: Well, I am practicing whatever I can. Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: you're welcome! it's all about using the right tool for the  job, happy to be of help

Comment: But then, better to use `label:active` it would have same effect without having to set `tabindex` attribute. Anyway, i don't think this is OP expected behaviour

Comment: good point, first instinct was just the css part, then realized that focus goes to input - adding tabindex to labels isn't really great for usability/a11y as it's not default behaviour. Best approach imho would be to do as I wrote in the second part of my answer

Comment: I have never heard of tab index but it is a really interesting attribute for me. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot trigger focus for a label using `.focus()` instead do it with `input`, Check here

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $('label').css('background', '#00CC66');
});
```

or

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).closest('label').css('background', '#00CC66');
});
```

Comment: You probably mean: `$(this).parent('label').css('background', '#00CC66');`

Comment: Ya exactly.. that would be a better solution

Comment: your solution as it is, would change the background of all `label` elements

Answer (score 2):

try this as you can't use focus on label -

```
$( "form input:radio" ).focus(function(){
            $(this).parent('label').css('background-color', '#00CC66');
        });
```